# Strange Play Framework And Hibernate Issue

Tags: hibernate, intellij-idea, playframework

We are working on a Play Framework + Hibernate project. And there's some special case with Hibernate which required us to dig in. We have removed all known Hibernate dependencies from Play Project (.e.g the ivy2 cache and our custom library folder). The strange thing is Play continue to run Hibernate as an included library!

IntelliJ shows that Hibernate is not within project's libraries:

[image]

But the Play project still run properly as if Hibernate is included. And if we try to debug we can see JVM loaded Hibernate but by no way we can step-in the code or see the class file from IntelliJ

[image]

Any advice is welcomed !

Comment: Add your build.sbt file, please.

Comment: Also, please, add which version of Play and Intellij IDEA you are using.

Comment: Did you `reload` in activator/sbt after changing `built.sbt`?

Answer (score 0):

We have fixed the problem by ourself. It seems we misunderstood IntelliJ & Play development. For anyone who comes across Play & IntelliJ, although Hibernate is removed from required library in IntelliJ, but it's SBT that will be kicked in at the beginning, and SBT may download Hibernate as part of symbol resolution process.

We had to put our custom built Hibernate into SBT ivy2 cache folder.